# After upgrade, iHeart Radio (on the web) no longer plays

Tags: internet-radio

I used to listen to a radio station (KNRS) online that uses iHeartRadio ([www.iheartradio.com](http://www.iheartradio.com)) for online radio.  After upgrading to 11.10, it no longer works.  In fact, I have to "force quit" to get out of it.  I can't check what format the service uses, as it freezes before I can do anything on the site.  However, it does work with Chromium.

I can listen to other stations that use different services (such as WLS-AM).  Flash, Banshee, VLC, etc., all work just fine, as far as I can tell.

This is the same on two computers: my desktop, and my laptop.  Has anyone else experienced this?  Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently installed the Flash-Aid plugin for Netscape, and had it get and install the latest 64-bit Flash.  I accepted all defaults during the process.  After doing so, I tried the radio station again and chose to listen live - and it worked just fine.  I think the Flash version that Flash-Aid intalled was a beta version, and evidently this is exactly what I needed.  (And so far, I haven't noticed anything that hasn't worked with it.)  Great!  Now I don't have to run Netscape and Chromium at the same time!

Answer (score 1):

There is a clue in this statement of yours:

> However, it does work with Chromium

The problem is not due to Ubuntu 11.10 but the other web browser that you want to use to listen to this Internet radio station.

When I try to access the same station using Chromium iheartradio.com blocks me because I do not live in the USA.

When I try using Firefox the program freezes (window greys out) due to using all available system memory and some more of swap memory. (I used System Monitor to check this). Future updates of Firefox might rectify this.

I use Radio Tray. It is in the Ubuntu Software Centre. I works well with Unit. It puts an icon in the top panel (an app-indicator). You can use it change stations. Right now I am listening to Heartland Public Radio (playing Roger Miller - Dang me). I am listening to an American Internet Radio Station without needing a web browser. It must be better.

You need the Internet address of the station's radio stream. You create a new station using that address in the Radio Tray Preferences>Configure Radios option.

The address for Heartland Public Radio is http://hpr1.hpr.org. The address for Country108 is http://tuner.country108.com:80.

I give you these as an example of what to look for. I cannot give the address of the stream for KNRS because I cannot play that station. If you find out the internet address of the KNRS radio stream then you might be able to use Radio Tray to play it. Either that or use Chromium.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, I'm listening on Chromium right now.  I haven't generally liked Chromium as much in the past (bad memory hole, at least on my system, and there is stupidly no way to disable tabs), so I've used Firefox.  Until upgrading to 11.10, it played iHeartRadio just fine; after the upgrade, it does too me what it does to you: greys out.  It's Firefox-specific, obviously, but I don't know if that means it's a problem in Firefox or in Ubuntu.  I'll definitely check out your radio solution!  That could be even better!  Thanks again!